# Run pdb from command line on application packaged as a zip file?

Tags: python, zip, pdb

Python is able to run code inside a zip archive.  This accounts for why some code starts with the familiar `#!/usr/bin/env python` followed immediately by the bytes of a raw zip file.
See e.g. http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2010/03/various-ways-of-distributing-python.html

Python also lets users run the python debugger conveniently on nearly any code from the command line, via the "-m pdb" option.  But running that on a zipped program (like the popular [youtube-dl program](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)) results in an encoding error like this:

```
$ python -m pdb /usr/bin/youtube-dl -h 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main 
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript 
    self.run(statement) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 387, in run 
    exec cmd in globals, locals 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xdb' in file /usr/bin/youtube-dl on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details 
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging 
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program 
> <string>(1)<module>() 
(Pdb)
```

The [referenced PEP 263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) doesn't talk about zip, and I'm not sure where this zip feature is officially described or implemented.

So my question is, is there a way to make this work for an arbitrary zip file, without unzipping it and running pdb on the `__main__.py` inside the zip?  Perhaps via an enhancement to pdb, or a wrapper around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 273](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/) - **Import Modules from Zip Archives** is a proposal that talk about that.

Therefore you can easily debug file inside the Zip archive as

```
python -c 'import pdb, youtube_dl; print youtube_dl; pdb.runcall(youtube_dl.main, ["-h"])' youtube-dl
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:          
$ python -c 'import pdb, youtube_dl; print youtube_dl; pdb.runcall(youtube_dl.main, ["-h"])' ./youtube-dl
Traceback (most recent call last):<b>

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named youtube_dl

Comment: Did you install youtube-dl?